# 13.04 boots into grub prompt

Tags: 13.04, grub2, windows-7

I have a dell xps 15". I've been running a dual boot setup for over a year. I recently moved to 13.04. About a week later my laptop (which is a work laptop) was remotely updated by IT on the windows side (I don't think they know about the ubuntu installation, but another IT guy did install it in the first place).

Since the windows update the ubuntu system boots into the grub prompt. I am not sure what to do. I've tried looking for the initrd file or something, but I can't seem to find my linux partitions...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be your display driver problem. maybe after updating your system the newest driver is not matched with our vga. Try uninstall your display driver and reinstall it.